# Intravenous Chameleon Injection

Tags: medical-myths, intravenous

If you were to liquefy an entire chameleon and inject it into someone's veins, what is the probability of survival?

Asking for a friend.

Comment: Sounds like a very imaginative way of getting anaphylactic shock.

Comment: A chameleon? As in [an animal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chameleon)? If that is the case, world building SE would be the place to ask. We generally don't liquefy chameleons on Earth. (If you are asking about something else please clarify).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is not a question about health.  It may fit better at World Building SE, or maybe Skeptics SE if you found stories about it.